# How to pass variant array to VB Com component from VC++

Tags: visual-c++, vb6, variant

I am calling VB COM component function from VC++ client,

This function expecting VARIANT array,

HRESULT setLabels (/[in,out]/VARIANT * labels)

I tried passing variant array in the following ways,

```
1)
void SetLabels()
{
  _variant_t arrayOfStrings[] = {"1","2","3","4" };
  setLabels(arrayOfStrings);
}

2) 

void SetLabels()
{
    SAFEARRAY *pArray;  
    StringArray strArray;
  strArray.push_back(_T("1,"));
  strArray.push_back(_T("2,"));
  strArray.push_back(_T("3,"));
  strArray.push_back(_T("4,"));
    ToSafeArray(&pArray, strArray);

    SAFEARRAY TEMPaRRAY;  
    TEMPaRRAY.vt = VT_ARRAY;
  TEMPaRRAY.parray = pArray;

    setLabels(arrayOfStrings);
}

void ToSafeArray(SAFEARRAY **saData, const StringArray& strArray)
{

 SAFEARRAYBOUND _SABound;
 ATLASSERT( saData );
    _SABound.lLbound = 0;
 _SABound.cElements = strArray.size();
 *saData = SafeArrayCreate( VT_BSTR, 1, &_SABound);
 BSTR *pData;
 SafeArrayAccessData(*saData, (void **)&pData );

 for ( UINT i=0; i<strArray.size(); ++i) 
         *(pData+i) = SysAllocString(strArray[i].c_str());

 SafeArrayUnaccessData(*saData);
}
```

In this both ways the VB component does not work as desired. Since i don't have source of VB component i don't know whats happening inside, The same component when I am accessing from VB client its working fine.

How to pass variant array to VB component from VC++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder what the "VARIANT ARRAY" means here. Is it an array of VARIANT type, or the parameter itself is of VARIANT type while the array can be of another type?

In both case, the variant containing the SAFEARRAY 's VARTYPE should be specified as a bitwise or of VT_ARRAY and the actual type it contains, in the original code it should be:

```
TEMPaRRAY.vt = VT_ARRAY | VT_BSTR;
```

If it is indeed an array of VARIANT, you should create your SafeArray to contain VARIANT

```
*saData = SafeArrayCreate( VT_VARIANT, 1, &_SABound);
```

and populate it with VARIANT containing BSTR:

```
VARIANT *pData;
SafeArrayAccessData(*saData, (void **)&pData );
 for ( UINT i=0; i<strArray.size(); ++i) {
    VAIRANT* p = (VARIANT*) pData+i;
    p->vt = VT_BSTR;
    p->bstrVal = SysAllocString(strArray[i].c_str());
 }
 SafeArrayUnaccessData(*saData);
```

Also I saw you missed the type declaration of TEMPaRRAY. Since your code is working this maybe only a typo.

Comment: Yes VARIANT ARRAY is an array of VARIANT type and also i missed type for TEMPARRAY and I editd now.